# V-lookup for multiple tabs in another worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

I will try and explain this as best I can.

worksheet 1 has two cells. 1st cell contains a 6 digit code (eg.123456).

Worksheet 2 contains several tabs, each tab will contain the 6 digit code and next to it a figuire.

I would like the 2nd cell in worksheet 1 to find the 6 digit codes in all of the tabs in worksheet 2 and total the figures next to them.

Is this possible with V-lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to sum the values in the column if they match the 6 digit code?

If so, sumif might be what you seek.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

sumif for arrays:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275165

Update:
Not a complete solution, but you could create a master table with the vba code below and create a pivot table on the summary table and do sum,counts, etc on all the unique 6 digit codes you want to summarize. You'll need to edit the range you're seeking and the range will have to be the same on all the worksheets. The "Summary-Table" worksheet will be created if not already there and be overwritten if it already exits.

```
Sub Summarize_Table_With_Formulas()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Newsh As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim Basebook As Workbook

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "Summary-Table" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary-Table").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Summary-Table"
    Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets.Add
    Newsh.Name = "Summary-Table"

    'The links to the first sheet will start in row 2
    RwNum = 1

    For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> Newsh.Name And Sh.Visible Then
            ColNum = 1
            RwNum = RwNum + 1
            'Copy the sheet name in the A column
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Sh.Name

            For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A1:B2")  '<--Change the range here
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
            Next myCell

        End If
    Next Sh

    Newsh.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

adapted VBA code from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win003.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not exactly. Next to the code will be another cell with a figure (only one cell not a whole column). This will be the same on all of the tabs. I want to total that cell from each of the tabs.